# What is the best approach to encapsulate multiple method calls?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there some principle to follow in multiple method calls on Java?

I know about Facade, but in single methods, not service methods, sometimes we need to call other single methods that have a single responsibility, but doing this, I will break this in this method then make multiple calls. For example:

```
private void doSomethingA(){

} 

private void doSomethingB(){

}   

private void doSomethingC(){

}  

//Am I breaking some rules here? What is the best approach?
private void processSomething(){
   doSomethingA();
   doSomethingB();
   doSomethingC();
}
```

Comment: You are breaking the rule that every statement must end with a semicolon..

Comment: If you really care about the OOP design right to the letter, you may read this
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29

Comment: Sorry about semicolon, is just an example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is perfectly acceptable, although your syntax is incorrect. Splitting large methods into smaller, more singly purposed, more readable, more testable methods and calling them from another method is good practice.

Comment: This. It actually is good practice to do it this way, especially if there is an order required in calling A, B or C. It also means that if every you need to do C, A, B or A, B, C, D  then you only update the method and not the thousand places you did A,B,C

Comment: @Joeblade or create a whole new method that runs those three processes in a different order. That said, You will be probably be better off creating a Finite-State-Machine.  I would read [this article](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state) for more information on how to create a State-Machine.

Comment: @hfontanez Actually I'd consider that overkill. I was describing simply methods that had to be called in order. like "loadFile", "parseFile", "readObjects" for example. there's a chance that at some point another method is needed in between loadFile and parseFile (resetParseState? just making this up) and it's better to change that in 1 place rather than many places

Comment: @Joeblade Obviously, we have a different of opinion. My opinion is that using a State pattern for this is way better solution than the proposed. Also notice that I said "I think (opinion) that you better off by..." The quick solution will be to do this for THIS SPECIFIC case. The problem with solutions like this is that they don't scale very well. What if instead of 3 methods you have 10? What then? The problem is that other people might come here and try to scale that solution and then run into all sorts of problems. After all, the question is "what is the BEST solution..."

Comment: Very good answers.... my question also is about how to identify when a class will encapsulate all methods to make an operation using all of them together...

Answer (score -1):

If there are a large number of processes or you use the same sequence often you could implement the processing as a sequence using an `enum`.

```
public enum Engine {

    A {

                @Override
                void doIt(Object to) {
                    // Do what you need to do.
                }
            },
    B {

                @Override
                void doIt(Object to) {
                    // Do what you need to do.
                }
            },
    C {

                @Override
                void doIt(Object to) {
                    // Do what you need to do.
                }
            };

    abstract void doIt(Object to);

    public void go(Object to) {
        for (Engine e : Engine.values()) {
            e.doIt(to);
        }
    }
}
```

This can be enhanced in many ways (which is why I like it). You can encode alternative orders of execution in an `Iterable`. You can add, remove and reorder the processes in just one place. The names of the enum can be greatly simplified. And many more.

Comment: This is a nice example of a state machine using Enum. I think this is the BEST approach because it is more scalable than "hard-coding" private methods inside a public methods. It also eliminate the confusion of having multiple public methods with different sequences because the caller will then be back to square one (not knowing which method to call). This approach it is all about context that is not controlled by the caller, but by the context.

Comment: um... this is just as static as hardcoding them in private methods. worse it hardcodes them in a static class, so you can't even override it. I prefer the real statemachine over this, as then at least you can add states during initialization if you need them, rather than recompiling.

Comment: I'm not convinced of the advantages of this pattern. You can add, remove and reorder processes in just one place using a method that calls child methods. This relies on the order of the enum in the same way that the method relies on the order of the calls. I would also argue that this isn't strictly what an enum was meant for - when reading code, I wouldn't be expecting to find this.

Comment: @RobertBain - You can chose your own order merely by providing a different Iterable (other than `Engine.values()`). I use this pattern often but I do a lot of data translation where it applies regularly. Do not shy away from unfamiliar constructs just because they are unexpected.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I understand that but I I would have thought that providing a new `Iterable` is more complicated than simply having another method that calls the child methods in a different order. You're essentially just wrapping the method calls in a particular order. Fair enough, perhaps it's useful. I'll have a play next time I find myself in a situation to which this approach may apply.